# How Can I turn in VSCode TailwindCSS Intellisense tips in dictionaries with specific names?

Tags: dictionary, visual-studio-code, styles, intellisense, tailwind-css

I store my Tailwind classes in reactapp in dictionaries:

```js
const styles = {
wrapper: "overflow-hidden pb-8 bg-red-50"
...
}
```

I want to have Intellisense tips there, which by default - doesn't work here.
I found the solution in TailwindCSS Intellisense extension settings:

```json
"tailwindCSS.classAttributes": [
    ""
  ]
```

The setting `""` make that Intellisense tips show inside strings in my `styles` dictionary BUT they also appear in every other string in every other dictionary ;_;

Is it possible to set showing TailwindCss Intellisense tips only in dictionaries with specific names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer right before i clicked "Post you question"

I don't believe it is that simple...

You can just put the name in the same option and it is working:

```json
"tailwindCSS.classAttributes": [
    "styles"
  ]
```

And now in every dictionary called `styles` I have Tailwind Intellisense tips, and i don't have them i other dictionaries. Awesome! :>